# Why does Vue's v-model update the data much more later after the click event was fired?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model, vue-directives

I have a very small checkbox component which I was trying to listen to via the @click event. But the v-model data updates 7ms later than the event callback. So I had to remove the @click listener and to add a computed property/method of the checked value and add a watch method for it to $emit the updated checked value. It works fine this way. But I just want to understand what's going behind the scenes. Can someone explain? Or maybe reference to a good resource on the net?

I also couldn't find the v-model methods in the Vue's source code. Where can I find v-model related code in the node_modules?

Answer (score 3):

You should try using `@change` instead and then print it for testing. For Example:

```
<input 
     type="checkbox" 
     v-model="item" 
     @change="sendEvent"
/>
```

```
sendEvent () {
     this.$emit('click', this.item);
},
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. I've upvoted your answer. But I would rather like to know why there is a delay and how v-model works internally and where to find all the related functions so I can observe the process and understand it better.

Comment: Well the best resource you can go to is the official documentation and understanding the life cycle: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: I know the life cycle process and the docs. I want to know more about the internals of vue.js related to v-model, means on the level of source code. But when I search for v-model in the node_modules there isn't anything that make sense at first glance.